# aws_wafv2_rule_group vs aws_wafregional_rule_group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-waf

i am trying to create a firewall manager policy using terraform. During the process i came across 2 resource groups for creating a rule group i.e. wasfv2_rule_group and wafregional_rule_group. i am confused to understand the difference between these 2 resources when creating an fms policy.
Since when i am creating a waf policy via console we don't see any difference between rule group for a region or without region.
Can someone please elaborate how these differ from one another and point to some documentation.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to use and explain what is the issue with it? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin there is no mention of any code or error in my question.
I am simply after more details to understand the difference b/w the two policies.